# Как посчитать общую продолжительность песен?

Tags: javascript

допустим есть массив объектов
нужно посчитать общую продолжительность звучания песен (песен может быть сколько угодно, в примере 3, но может быть  5
или 10, не суть важно)

**пример**

первая песня - 1 минута

вторая - 1 минута

третья - 1 минуты 5 секунд

вывести в див  03:05

```js
[
  {
    url: './assets/sounds/song1.mp3',
    name: '111',
  },
  {
    url: './assets/sounds/song2.mp3',
    name: 'test22',
  },
  {
    url: './assets/sounds/song3.mp3',
    name: 'test33',
  },
]
```

Comment: посчитать очень просто - взять продолжительность каждой песни и сложить их поочередно. В чем вопрос-то?

Comment: откуда их взять?

Comment: @Эникейщик проблема в том, что нужно сначала загрузить эти аудио по урлу, каждую отдельно, после загрузки колбеком получить `duration`, разом все не получить, повозится надо

Comment: @user520486 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647536/how-to-get-audio-duration-value-by-a-function тут как получить `duration` одной песни по урлу

Answer (score 0):

Соберите все МП3-файлы в одну папку. В окне появится кнопка "выберите файлы". Выделите все МП3-файлы в этой папке и нажмите "выбрать". Результат увидите. Если вдруг вместо числа минут выскочит NaN, то попробуйте ещё раз. Даже если выберите не все МП3-файлы из папки, то подсчитается сумарная длительность звучания только выбранных файлов.

```html
<html>
<body bgcolor=#ccc><center><h3>Утилита для определения сумарной длительности звучания</h3>
<div id=vybor>
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="myfile" onchange="mysum(this.files)">
</div><br>
<div id=resultat></div>
<script>
function mysum(e){
    resultat.innerHTML="подождите...";
    b=0;
    for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++){
        a=new Audio(e[i].name);
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        setTimeout(function(){
            b+=a.duration;
            resultat.innerHTML="Сумарная длительность звучания всех выбранных МП3-файлов: <b>" + Math.round(b/60) + "</b> минут";
        },500);
    }
}
vybor.innerHTML=vybor.innerHTML;
</script>
<center></body>
</html>
```

Этот код писался раньше, чуть позже опишу, как задействовать Ваш json.